# Remove all comments without a TODO

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

This is a java project using intellij idea (but the solution doesn't have to use intellij, `sed` or whatever would be fine).  I'd like to delete all comments in my .java files that **don't** have the word `todo` in it (case-insensitive).  How do I do that?

I don't want the comments to become blank lines.  I want the whole line to disappear.

All comments start like this:

```
//
```

I tried this in intellij:

```
^\s*//.*?[^Tt][^Oo][^Dd][^Oo].*?\n
```

But that's still grabbing lines with `TODO` in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this regex can help you :

```
^\s*\/\/.*\btodo\b.*$
```

<kbd>[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgsmo3/1)</kbd>

which mean :

- `^` start of line
- `\s*` zero or more space
- `\/\/` literal `//`
- `.*` zero or more character
- `\btodo\b` word boundary todo
- `.*` zero or more character
- `$` end of line

---

> I want the inverse of these results

In this case you can use

```
^(?i)\s*\/\/((?!todo).)*$
```

<kbd>[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IFtBa9/1)</kbd>

Comment: I want the all the comments that are NOT these results.

Comment: what did you mean by *inverse of these results* ? check my edit hope this is what you want!

Comment: Yep, that's it.  I forgot that you can do ?!.  Thanks

Comment: This isn't case insensitive, but I imagine I can put a [] and | in there

Comment: for case insensitive you can use `(?i)` in the begging check my edit